# Get color of target html element in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, css-modules

Trying to get the color of an html element using react, to pass to to my redux action/reducer.

**JSX**

```
<div>
   <button styleName="css_toggle" id ="css" onClick {this.handleClick}>CSS</button>
</div>
```

**Event Handler**

```
handleClick(e){
  const{dispatch} = this.props;
  console.log(`e.target: ${e.target.style}`);
  dispatch(CurrView(e.target.id, e.target.style.background));
}
```

Console/redux console returns empty values for all styles.

I am using react-css-modules/css-modules, and that is the only anomaly I can think of.

Any ideas are more than welcome, thank you.

Edit: I have created a branch specifically for this stackoverflow question: https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/pixelLight/tree/stackoverflow-37583025

Note: The data flow of this app, is that there is a single static value, which populates the rest of the app which is dynamic. In response, to suggestion(s), after much thought, I have decided this is the proper way to architect the app.

Comment: className instead of styleName. working on answer

Comment: @CoryDanielson I am using react-css-modules, which uses styleName, meant to include webpackbin, and might still if my question turns out to be too confusing. Thank you.

Comment: ah interesting, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used

```
const backgroundStyle = window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

and that allowed me to get the proper value. I would assume this is as result of two things going on, in this app.

1. Style tags are being injected in the html directly. Not 100% if it as a result of webpack-dev-server or react-css-modules.
2. Styles are only applied after react app is initialized, with proper settings applied.

So there it is, in this situation, getting the computed style is what did it for me. I am still in the process of looking into particular details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs to reliable reference an element.

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

JSX

```
<div>
    <button id ="css"
        styleName="css_toggle"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        ref={(e) => { this.cssToggleButton = e; }}>
        CSS
    </button>
</div>
```

Event Handler

```
handleClick() {
    const id = this.cssToggleButton.id;
    const background = this.cssToggleButton.style.background;
    this.props.dispatch(id, background);
}
```

Comment: No dice. Unfortunately, it is still showing up as an empty style. I am going to update my question with a webpackbin, or something similar.

Comment: Did it return the `id` properly? Maybe instead of `style.background` you need `style.backgroundColor` instead. You should definitely be using refs for this.

Comment: id is returned for both target and refs. However, style.backgroundColor, or style.background is not being returned for either target or refs.

Comment: How are you updating the background color of this element? Are you adding a new class name?

Comment: Also, this approach seems inherently fragile, because it depends on the specifics of CSS. It would be more reliable to have whatever is updating the style of this element to also update state of the component with this new color. Inspecting the DOM for data is backwards to the react approach, of updating data and re-rendering the DOM... but I'm not sure if this is possible  since I don't know too much about the code.